# How do I call a stored procedure with unconventional parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm attempting to integrate Red Gate's SQLBackup Pro software into my in-house backup software, written in C#. The natural way to do this is via their [Extended Stored Procedure](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SQL_Backup/help/6.5/SBU_UsingStoredProc). The problems is that it's called in a format I've never seen before:

```
master..sqlbackup '-SQL "BACKUP DATABASE pubs TO DISK = [C:\Backups\pubs.sqb]"'
```

This works just fine when run via SSMS. Where I run into trouble is trying to call it from C# (using .NET 4 and [Dapper Dot Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)).

My first attempt doesn't work because it interprets the entire `cmd` string as the name of the stored procedure and throws the error "Cannot find stored procedure ''":

```
var cmd = "master..sqlbackup '-SQL \"BACKUP DATABASE pubs TO DISK = [C:\\Backups\\pubs.sqb]\"'";
connection.Execute(cmd, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 0);
```

My second attempt returns immediately and appears (to C#) to succeed, but no backup is actually taken (this also sucks for parameterization):

```
var cmd = "master..sqlbackup";
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("", "'-SQL \"BACKUP DATABASE pubs TO DISK = [C:\\Backups\\pubs.sqb]\"'");
connection.Execute(cmd, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 0);
```

My third attempt also appears to succeed, but no backup is actually taken:

```
var cmd = "master..sqlbackup '-SQL \"BACKUP DATABASE pubs TO DISK = [C:\\Backups\\pubs.sqb]\"'";
connection.Execute(cmd, commandTimeout: 0);
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

I overlooked the Red Gate documentation that says the stored proc won't actually raise a SQL error, it just returns errors in an output table. Slick. This might explain why I was getting silent failures in the second and third tests above: some underlying problem and they're not collecting the output to show why.

Here's where I am now:

```
var cmd = "master..sqlbackup";
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("", "'-SQL \"BACKUP DATABASE pubs TO DISK = [C:\\Backups\\pubs.sqb]\"'");
p.Add("@exitcode", DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@sqlerrorcode", DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
connection.Execute(cmd, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 0);
```

When I run this and check those output parameters, I get Exit Code 870:

> No command passed to SQL Backup.
>
> The command is empty.

So it's not seeing the empty-named paramater.

**Update 2:**

Capturing the above in a trace shows that the empty parameter string ends up replaced with `@Parameter1=` which explains why the stored procedure doesn't see it.

Comment: do an sp_help on sqlbackup, I am sure that param has a name

Comment: `sp_help sqlbackup` only includes the Name, Owner, Type, and Created_datetime columns. Even though type is "extended stored proc" there's no param_order (or whatever it's called) column...

Comment: I opened a case with Red Gate to find out if that param has a name. We'll see.

Comment: According to Red Gate, this parameter has no name. It just uses whatever's in the first position. That seems silly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gross and not at all what I wanted, but this is what I've got working now:

```
var cmd = String.Format(@"
DECLARE @exitcode int; 
DECLARE @sqlerrorcode int;
EXEC master..sqlbackup '-SQL \"BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO DISK = [{1}])\"', @exitcode OUTPUT, @sqlerrorcode OUTPUT;
IF (@exitcode >= 500) OR (@sqlerrorcode <> 0)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('SQLBackup failed with exitcode %d and sqlerrorcode %d ', 16, 1, @exitcode, @sqlerrorcode)
END
", myDbName, myBkpPath);

connection.Execute(cmd, commandTimeout: 0);
```

This executes the backup and actually returns failure status, which exposed an underlying issue that caused the failure part of the silent failures.

Before it runs, myDbName is checked against a list of known databases to ensure it exists and myBkpPath is generated by my code, so I'm not worried about injections. It's just...well, look at that. Hideous.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt looks almost right.  What I notice is that you failed to escape the backslashes.  For this kind of thing, it's often easier to use the @ prefix to disable escaping for the string.  Also, you want to prepend with exec and make it `CommandType.Text`:

EDIT: fixed my own escaping bugs here

```
var cmd = @"exec 'master..sqlbackup -SQL ""BACKUP DATABASE pubs TO DISK = [C:\Backups\pubs.sqb]""'";
connection.Execute(cmd, commandType: CommandType.Text, commandTimeout: 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, the backslashes actually were escaped but that didn't come through in the question. I chose to escape them rather than use `@""` syntax because the quotes were already the most confusing part and the paths (once this is figured out) will be inserted via parameters or (god forbid) string formatting.

Comment: Did you try adding the exec as I also mentioned?

Comment: Yes. Same result as #2 and #3: returns immediately without doing any work, but doesn't appear to fail.

Comment: @sh-beta: more to the point, did you change yours from CommandType.StoredProcedure to CommandType.Text?  That's the main problem.

Comment: @ChrisLively Yes. See the third attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a typical stored procedure that calls the extended stored procedure, and calling that from code? It looks like you have only a few parameters to deal with here.

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but isn't a very scalable solution since the stored procedure in question would have to be created and managed on every one of my SQL servers.

Comment: Isn't the extended stored procedure on every server? What do you mean by 'managed'?

Comment: The extended stored procedure is part of a software package with a network-aware installer that lets you trivially push it to and upgrade it across a network. I'm not saying this is impossible with a stored procedure but that I'd rather just get my code working with what's already out there.

Answer (score 0):

You had several problems in your tests.

In the first one you set the `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.  You should have set it to `CommandType.Text` so that it would be smart enough to just pass that string along to be exec'd.

In the subsequent examples, you didn't actually give the parameter a name.  Go look at their SqlBackup procedure and see what the parameter names are.  Then use it.  Otherwise, nothing is going to be assigned to it.

Comment: Both these problems are explained in my question. The first: "My first attempt doesn't work because it interprets the entire cmd string as the name of the stored procedure and throws the error Cannot find stored procedure ''". My third attempt is exactly this, but the backup silently failed. For the second, see my comments on my question. The parameter has no documented name.

Comment: @sh-beta: you can inspect the proc in order to determine the parameter names.  No need for documentation.  Even encrypted procs will tell you what the names of the parameters are.  In management studio you can expand the stored proc definition and look at the parameters list.  Or you can just right click on the proc and script it so that you can get the name of the parameter.

Comment: this one doesn't give anything useful. The entire scripted definition is "EXEC dbo.sp_addextendedproc N'sqlbackup', ''"